# Django error with csrf_token

Tags: django, migration, csrf

I'm migrating a project from django 1.3 to 1.5, and I have this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://192.168.13.190/val/admin/

Django Version: 1.5.8
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'dxp.workflow2',
 'django_extensions',
 'south',
 'revisions',
 'dajax',
 'dajaxice',
 'django.contrib.admindocs')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'revisions.middleware.VersionedModelRedirectMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  138.                     response = response.render()
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  82.         content = template.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  844.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  844.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  124.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  844.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  63.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_node
  844.         return node.render(context)
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  1208.                         new_context['csrf_token'] = csrf_token
File "/home/dxpadmin/lsf_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/context.py" in __setitem__
  50.         self.dicts[-1][key] = value

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

In the log I don't see any relation with the code of the project, I've tried to deactivated csrf_token in both my project and the middeware list, but the problem persists

Comment: Do you have any context processors that are returning a string?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you have a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) that returns a string instead of a dict.